# Why is local hosting of ArcGIS Online webmap giving error?

Tags: error, arcgis-online, hosting

I have been trying to locally host this webmap I created using AGOL (to modify it):

http://dpwh.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapTour/index.html?appid=7bd06d8330254b2688577d82f81bb92e

It uses the Map Tour template. I did step 1 of the readme file, and since I already had built the application inAGOL, skipped to step 5 and configured  configOptions to use the appid, such as it now looks like this

```
configOptions = {
                // Enter either a web map ID or a web application ID
                // - Using a Map Tour application ID created through the interactive builder in ArcGIS.com allow to reuse 
                //   the settings like the header configuration without having to edit any configuration here
                // - Web map and application can be dynamically specified through url parameters (webmap and appid) 
                //   if the authorizedOwners property is specified (see below)
                // - If an application id is specified, the webmap configuration isn't used
                webmap: "",
                appid: "7bd06d8330254b2688577d82f81bb92e",
                // Optional list of authorized application or web map owners
                // Has to be specified when using appid or webmap url parameters (e.g. ["user1"], ["user1", "user2"])
                authorizedOwners: [""],
                // Select the application layout between "three-panel" and "integrated"
                layout: "three-panel",
                // The application header title, if no title is specified, the webmap's title is used
                title: "",
                // The application header subtitle, if not specified the ArcGIS.com web map's summary is used
                subtitle: "",
                // Optionally force a web map layer to be used as the tour points data source (can be overridden through URL)
                // Otherwise the upper visible point layer is used (excluding map notes)
                sourceLayerTitle: "",
                // Use the first data record as an introduction instead of a point (can be overridden through URL)
                firstRecordAsIntro: true,
                // Optional zoom level to be applied for the story points following introduction (can be overridden through URL) (e.g: 0 to 16 for Gray Canvas, 0 to 19 for Street Map, -1 to disable)
                zoomLevel: -1
            };
```

Loading the local version however only produces a "Fatal error: Failed to get portal configuration" error. This is the case even if I only use the webmap id, or just load the page unmodified.

Help please to make this work?

Comment: Hi, anyone? =) =)

Comment: To try and draw attention to this Question your best bet will be to consider editing it to a revised form that may be more Answer-able.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are doubling up on the id. Either leave it blank in the config options i.e. appid: "" and use it in the url i.e. http://dpwh.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapTour/index.html?appid=7bd06d8330254b2688577d82f81bb92e or use it in the config i.e. appid: "7bd06d8330254b2688577d82f81bb92e", and leave it out of the url i.e. http://dpwh.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapTour/